# Updating page template pragmatically

Tags: pages, templates

While I understand that there are many similar questions answered which helped me find a solution to update the page template for my custom post type pragmatically and it works correctly.

However, my difficulty is in finding a solution to update the `body_classes` that matches the page template. Right now, the body classes are not updated when the page template is updated pragmatically.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_template_include', 99, 1 );
function my_template_include( $template ) {
    global $post;

    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'designblocks-product-template', true );

    if ( ! $meta ) {
        return $template;
    }

    $get_template = get_post_meta( $meta, '_wp_page_template', true );

    if ( $get_template ) {
        $template = locate_template( array( $get_template ) );
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Body classes, right? Did you use your own header.php? You may add the same mechanism to your <body> in header.php for outputting the classes. eg. `<body <?php body_class( trim( $body_classes ) ); ?>>` where you could prepare your own $body_classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `body_class` filter to change the `<body>` CSS classes.

You can copy the same logic into your hooked function (like below), or make it neater by copying the logic into another new function and make this function return a boolean (and then use that new function with the body_class filter and within your template_redirect filter.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function($body_classes){
    global $post;

    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'designblocks-product-template', true );

    if ( ! $meta ) {
        return $body_classes;
    }

    $get_template = get_post_meta( $meta, '_wp_page_template', true );

    if ( $get_template ) {
        $body_classes[] = 'your-custom-classes';
    }

    return $body_classes;
});
```

Though, if I understood correctly what it is you're trying to do, then you're making your life unnecessarily difficult trying to replicate WP's native page template functionality and related things. Instead, just create a file in your theme called `single-{post-type-name}.php` and use this instead of assigning a page template. The `<body>` will be given a class of `single-{post-type-name}`.

Comment: You're right. I am trying to automate the body_classes instead of manually adding them. This is a plugin I am trying to build and what I am trying to do add support for page templates in custom CPT.

Comment: I don't want to add classes manually as they differ from theme to theme.

Comment: @Haris do you mean you want the class to be named something that is specific to the template? If yes, you could still use the `body_class` filter and then make the CSS class name something that is unique to that template, e.g. my-template-name-class (this name you could create based on the `_wp_page_template` meta value).